# Append JSON array to existing JSON array

Tags: javascript, json

I have two JSON array of objects - `cads` and `uploads`:

```
{
   "cad":[
      {
         "cad_id":246,
         "call_operator":"controller",
         "user_id":"136",
         "date":"2017-12-12 20:44:30",
      }
   ],
   "uploads":[
      {
         "file_id":"1",
         "cad_id":"246",
         "file_category":"prf",
         "file_name":"e9283220bacfe5ca5c6a7edadef37e83.pdf"
      },
      {
         "file_id":"2",
         "cad_id":"246",
         "file_category":"radio_log",
         "file_name":"62d72ee7f69e17b54848df082dd72323.pdf"
      }
   ]
}
```

I would like to take the `uploads` array and append it to the `cads` array so that it's within the `cads` array, rather than having two separate arrays.

```
{
   "cad":[
      {
         "cad_id":246,
         "call_operator":"controller",
         "user_id":"136",
         "date":"2017-12-12 20:44:30",
         "uploads":[
          {
             "file_id":"1",
             "cad_id":"246",
             "file_category":"prf",
             "file_name":"e9283220bacfe5ca5c6a7edadef37e83.pdf"
          },
          {
             "file_id":"2",
             "cad_id":"246",
             "file_category":"radio_log",
             "file_name":"62d72ee7f69e17b54848df082dd72323.pdf"
          }
       ]
      }
   ]
}
```

There is only ever 1 element in the `cad` array if that helps. The `uploads` array can have multiple items.

How do I do this in JS (or jQuery)?

Comment: really [JSON](http://json.org/)? a string representation of an object?

Answer (score 0):

Just assign `uploads` to the place where you want it.

```
data.cad[0].uploads = data.uploads;
```

This assumes the JSON has been parsed into JS objects, held by the `data` variable.

---

You can then delete the original `uploads` property if you wish.

```
delete data.uploads;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it -

```js
var json = {
   "cad":[
      {
         "cad_id":246,
         "call_operator":"controller",
         "user_id":"136",
         "date":"2017-12-12 20:44:30",
      }
   ],
   "uploads":[
      {
         "file_id":"1",
         "cad_id":"246",
         "file_category":"prf",
         "file_name":"e9283220bacfe5ca5c6a7edadef37e83.pdf"
      },
      {
         "file_id":"2",
         "cad_id":"246",
         "file_category":"radio_log",
         "file_name":"62d72ee7f69e17b54848df082dd72323.pdf"
      }
   ]
}
var  newObj= {};
newObj.cad = json.cad;
newObj.cad[0].uploads=  json.uploads;
console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myArray = {
   "cad":[
      {
         "cad_id":246,
         "call_operator":"controller",
         "user_id":"136",
         "date":"2017-12-12 20:44:30",
      }
   ],
   "uploads":[
      {
         "file_id":"1",
         "cad_id":"246",
         "file_category":"prf",
         "file_name":"e9283220bacfe5ca5c6a7edadef37e83.pdf"
      },
      {
         "file_id":"2",
         "cad_id":"246",
         "file_category":"radio_log",
         "file_name":"62d72ee7f69e17b54848df082dd72323.pdf"
      }
   ]
};
myArray.cad[0].uploads = myArray.uploads;
var newArray = myArray.cad;
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to combine the arrays by `cad_id`:

```js
let obj = {"cad":[{"cad_id":246,"call_operator":"controller","user_id":"136","date":"2017-12-12 20:44:30",}],"uploads":[{"file_id":"1","cad_id":"246","file_category":"prf","file_name":"e9283220bacfe5ca5c6a7edadef37e83.pdf"},{"file_id":"2","cad_id":"246","file_category":"radio_log","file_name":"62d72ee7f69e17b54848df082dd72323.pdf"}]};

obj = obj.uploads.reduce((a, b) => {
    const e = a.find(e => e.cad_id == b.cad_id);
    if (! e) return a; // change this to do something different with a not found cat_id
    e.uploads = (e.uploads || []).concat(b);
    return a;
}, obj.cad);

console.log(obj);
```

Note that above doesn't do anything if the `cat` array doesn't have an item with the given `cat_id`. You can change that behaviour to create a new category, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over each upload and find the corresponding cad. Create the property if it doesn't exist and add that upload to it. Then finally delete `data.uploads`

```js
data.uploads.forEach(u => {
  var cad = data.cad.find(c => +c.cad_id === +u.cad_id) ||{};     
  cad.uploads = (cad.uploads || []).concat(u);     
});

delete data.uploads;

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script>
  var data = {
    "cad": [{
      "cad_id": 246,
      "call_operator": "controller",
      "user_id": "136",
      "date": "2017-12-12 20:44:30",
    }],
    "uploads": [{
        "file_id": "1",
        "cad_id": "246",
        "file_category": "prf",
        "file_name": "e9283220bacfe5ca5c6a7edadef37e83.pdf"
      },
      {
        "file_id": "2",
        "cad_id": "246",
        "file_category": "radio_log",
        "file_name": "62d72ee7f69e17b54848df082dd72323.pdf"
      }
    ]
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a hash table for getting the elements with the same `cad_id` and push the upload objects to the right array.

After the assignments delete the property `upload` from the object.

```js
var data = { cad: [{ cad_id: 246, call_operator: "controller", user_id: "136", date: "2017-12-12 20:44:30" }], uploads: [{ file_id: "1", cad_id: "246", file_category: "prf", file_name: "e9283220bacfe5ca5c6a7edadef37e83.pdf" }, { file_id: "2", cad_id: "246", file_category: "radio_log", file_name: "62d72ee7f69e17b54848df082dd72323.pdf" }] },
    hash = Object.create(null);

data.cad.forEach(function (o) {
    hash[o.cad_id] = (o.uploads = []);
});

data.uploads.forEach(function (o) {
    hash[o.cad_id].push(o);
});

delete data.uploads;

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```